# rebasing with autosquash doesn't work as expected

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to squash last 3 commits using `autosquash` options provided by git-rebase. I have the following history:

```
* commit 78a7e4844fa32d2ef1bb7bd9b44c4a1b9551d31a (HEAD, new)
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Fri Feb 20 10:29:48 2015 +0200
|
|     squash! s3
|
* commit f25491cadc646baf14bd7e951245c6777230a1d7
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Fri Feb 20 10:29:42 2015 +0200
|
|     squash! s2
|
* commit b988237356ffb59752e49049d083c558373f9486
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Fri Feb 20 10:29:24 2015 +0200
|
|     squash! s1
|
* commit abbcdc833e5eaabe79681bd82087b4d7969e8599 (new1, ne, 9484)
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Wed Feb 18 18:21:58 2015 +0200
|
|     3
```

So I want commits with messages `s1`, `s2` and `s3` prefixed with `squash!` to be squashed. Now I issue the following command:

```
$ git rebase -i abbcdc833 --autosquash
```

And so git opens a text editor with the following content:

```
pick b988237 squash! s1
pick f25491c squash! s2
pick 78a7e48 squash! s3
```

But I expected it to be like this:

```
pick b988237 squash! s1
squash f25491c squash! s2
squash 78a7e48 squash! s3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure to use Git 2.20+ (Q4 2018) when doing a `rebase --autostash`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52504818/6309

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the documentation, but emphasis mine:

> When the commit log message begins with "squash! ..." (or "fixup!
>              ..."), **and there is a commit whose title begins with the same ...**,
>              automatically modify the todo list of `rebase -i` so that the commit
>              marked for squashing comes right after the commit to be modified,
>              and change the action of the moved commit from pick to squash (or
>              fixup). Ignores subsequent "fixup! " or "squash! " after the first,
>              in case you referred to an earlier fixup/squash with `git commit --fixup/--squash`.

Your first `squash!` has `s3` as its `...` portion.  So, rebase looks for a commit that has `s3` as its "title" (this is never defined in the documentation, but it appears to mean "one-line description", i.e., the first line of the log message).  There are no such commits in the list.

Moving on to the second, we find the same problem, and likewise with the third.

If your first commit (with title `s1`) were followed by a commit whose title was `squash! s1`, that particular one would get a "squash" word.

(Note that `git commit --fixup=<id>` or `git commit --squash=<id>` will create this kind of "same title" commit for you.  The "ignores subsequent" stuff is because you can do this while working:

```
git add ...; git commit -m thing1
... edit ...
git add ...; git commit -m thing2
# now fix thing1 bug noticed while working on thing2
... edit ...
git add ...; git commit --no-edit --fixup=HEAD^
... edit/test some more, discover fixup was not complete
git add ...; git commit --no-edit --fixup=HEAD
```

In this case, the *second* fixup's line is `fixup! fixup! thing1`; rebase just looks for a commit whose "title" is `thing1`, again.)

Comment: thanks a lot! You're of great help to me on my way to learning Git :). I've tried with equal message and it did the trick. The interesting thing is that after I rebase commits after `abbcd` the `squash` doesn't work. Any idea why it that?

Comment: there is also a mentioning of the `rebase.autosquash` option with the exlanation: `If set to true enable --autosquash option by default.`. Does it mean that if this option is `true` I don't need to specify `--autosquash` with `git rebase` and git will automatically look for commits with `squash!`?

Comment: For the topic to match and autosquash to do its thing, the one-line text must be in the set of commands that `rebase -i` is going to execute.  Think of it this way: `rebase -i` first makes a complete list of nothing but `pick` commands.  Then, if autosquash is on, the rebase script looks for lines that have `squash!` and `fixup!` right after the commit-ID part.  It takes those lines and treats them as "instructions for modifying another pick line".  If there isn't a pick line to modify, the instructions are left alone; if there *is* a pick line to modify, the instructions are followed.

Comment: And, yes, `rebase.autosquash = true` means that `--autosquash` is done automatically (`rebase` has a `--no-autosquash` option to turn it off manually for one rebase, if needed, or of course you can change your configuration options).

Comment: In my experience, it's simpler to just use 'git reset <first commit>' and then [git commit --amend](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history). Just be sure to avoid using using 'git reset --hard' in that case! For example, if you have 4 commits on a feature branch, and you want the last 3 'squashed' into the first one, you can use 'git reset <1st commit>', then use 'git commit --amend ...' (see git docs for complete usage).

Comment: @ArchStanton: I don't use this mode much myself, I'm just describing how it's intended to be used. I tried it out a few times and decided it wasn't for me...

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was:

```
pick b988237 ...
squash f25491c ...
squash 78a7e48 ...
```

you would have need the following commit messages:

```
* commit 78a7e4844fa32d2ef1bb7bd9b44c4a1b9551d31a (HEAD, new)
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Fri Feb 20 10:29:48 2015 +0200
|
|     squash! s1
|
* commit f25491cadc646baf14bd7e951245c6777230a1d7
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Fri Feb 20 10:29:42 2015 +0200
|
|     squash! s1
|
* commit b988237356ffb59752e49049d083c558373f9486
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Fri Feb 20 10:29:24 2015 +0200
|
|     s1
|
* commit abbcdc833e5eaabe79681bd82087b4d7969e8599 (new1, ne, 9484)
| Author: maxim koretskyi <mkoretskyi@company.com>
| Date:   Wed Feb 18 18:21:58 2015 +0200
|
|     3
```

leading to:

```
pick b988237 s1
squash f25491c squash! s1
squash 78a7e48 squash! s1
```

Note: after the `squash!`  the *commit message* must be use as reference for the squash target.

With the commit messages as above you would get the interactive editor content by either:

```
git rebase -i b988237356ffb59752e49049d083c558373f9486 --autostash
```

or with `rebase.autostash` set to true the flag can be omitted and the regular rebase interactive command is sufficient:

```
git rebase -i b988237356ffb59752e49049d083c558373f9486
```